# Alfresco CMIS query with dynamic date

Tags: alfresco, cmis

I want to query Alfresco through the CMIS query interface. I can not find any documentation on how to query with a condition on a dynamic date, e.g. today.

I want to retrieve changes within the last 24 hours. So what I am looking for is an equivalent to the SQL NOW.

E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM cmis:document WHERE cmis:lastModificationDate >= NOW() - 1 DAY
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAICS there's nothing in the [spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.0/os/cmis-spec-v1.0.html) about such a feature. You need to calculate dynamic datetime values as part of the logic that builds the query, then translate it into a [literal](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS_Query_Language#comparison_predicate):

```
SELECT * FROM cmis:document WHERE cmis:lastModificationDate < TIMESTAMP '2010-04-01T00:00:00.000+00:00'
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I did it programmatically.